# SCons: How to import a Python module in an SConscript which has been invoked with VariantDir?

Tags: scons, python-import

My build is structured like:

```
SConstruct
subdir/SConscript
subdir/module/__init__.py
```

`SConstruct` invokes `subdir/SConscript` as a subsidiary:

```
# SConstruct
SConscript('subdir/SConscript')
```

`subdir/SConscript` imports `module`:

```
# subdir/SConscript
from module import foo
do SConsy stuff with foo()...
```

This works fine until I use `variant_dir` with `subdir/SConscript`:

```
# SConstruct
SConscript('subdir/SConscript', variant_dir='subdir/build', duplicate=0)
```

The problem is that the `import` fails because `module` is no longer in the path, which has been altered by `variant_dir`.

Is there a standard way to solve this problem in either SCons or Python? I know about the special `site_scons` directory, but it appears that this directory must exist at the top level with the root `SConstruct`, and I'd like to keep `subdir`-specific files under `subdir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use site_scons dir in project root dir for you module. For example i've module xxx, and he is placed : `root/site_scons/xxx/__init__.py`. Now, i can import xxx in all of my SConscript files.

Comment: You could also pass the -I or --include-dir options to scons which allow you to specify the path to the python modules, but this may be more difficult (more typing each time you execute scons) unless you wrap your call to the scons script in another script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually trying to avoid using the `site_scons` directory and ultimately went with the solution below, but I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

In the `SConscript`, before the `import`, alter Python's path:

```
# subdir/SConscript
module_path = Dir('.').srcnode().abspath # get the path to subdir
import sys
sys.path.append(module_path)
from module import foo
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me as I had no access to root folder, but I wanted to create single file with defines in script folder.

Answer (score 0):

export  PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir_of_modules

This worked for me