# How can I call Scons from a Python program as a library?

Tags: python, scons

I have a Python program, whose workflow over a set of files that could be nicely expressed using "build" dependencies with Scons as follows:

- Construct a temporary `SConstruct` file that describes the dependencies and rules to build targets.

  - Represent the Python functions that produce targets as [`Builder`s](https://scons.org/doc/0.96/HTML/scons-user/x2134.html).
  - [Import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9832353/1333025) the builders in the `SConstruct` file.
- Run `scons` on the `SConstruct` file.

Is it possible to eliminate the creation of `SConstruct` file and calling `scons` on it, and do that directly from my Python program? After all, `SConstruct` is a Python program, just that it's called by `scons` in a special fashion.

Comment: It's not that easy to tell what, exactly, you're asking.  The "SCons Public API" can mostly be obtained by doing `from SCons.Script import *`.  It's not entirely trivial to get a consistent environment from this, because some things are dynamically created - in particular builders, so they might not be available at import time, but it turns out some well-known builder names are phonied up so it may or may not work.  But the idea of evaluating a script file to set up how things are going to work is ingrained in the SCons program flow, so it sounds like, absent details - it's pretty unlikely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, yes.

Recommended, very much not so.  It was never designed with that type of usage and so doing so will be very complicated, and it is not a supported usage by the SCons maintainers.

See Mats [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449101/how-can-i-call-scons-from-a-python-program-as-a-library#comment136541133_77449101) for some of the details why.

I'd keep using the flow you've got working now. You won't simplify anything by embedding SCons.